# I exceeded the 10GB free tier, so I deleted some files but it wont let me push the changes

Tags: gitlab, quota

I have a gitlab free-tier account and this morning I found that we have exceeded our 10GB limit, and so I used BFG to remove them from the history and should now be well under the limit but I can't push the changes to the repo.

It seems like I need to have the quota temporarily increased, so I submitted a ticket to the support portal but I immediately got a reply saying that the ticket was closed because I do not have a paid account.

Is there a way around deleting the project and creating a new one? I would like to keep all of our issues, wiki pages, code reviews, etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replied to the automatic email asking for help even though I don't have a paid account and they responded about a day later by lifting the limit temporarily to let me push a fix. :)